# dynamic table layout inside autocomplete textview in android

Tags: android, android-tablelayout

Hi in the below Implemented dynamic table layout with header names are fixed.In the same way implemeted autocomplete textview.

Now want to combine these two into single implementation.

Can any one help me .

Expected output:

```
Product Name           Quantity           Unit Price         Total
Autocompletetextview   dynamically want to change remaining tabel rows data
```

Java:

```
 TableRow tbrow0 = new TableRow(getContext());
                Resources resource = getContext().getResources();
                tbrow0.setLayoutParams(getLayoutParams());
                tbrow0.addView(getTextView(0, "Product Name", Color.WHITE, Typeface.NORMAL, resource.getColor(R.color.tabs1)));
                tbrow0.addView(getTextView(0, "Quantity", Color.WHITE, Typeface.NORMAL,resource.getColor(R.color.tabs1)));
                tbrow0.addView(getTextView(0, "Unit Price", Color.WHITE, Typeface.NORMAL, resource.getColor(R.color.tabs1)));
                tbrow0.addView(getTextView(0, "Total", Color.WHITE, Typeface.NORMAL, resource.getColor(R.color.tabs1)));
                stk.addView(tbrow0,getLayoutParams());
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, product_name);
            autoproduct_name.setAdapter(adapter);
            autoproduct_name.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    if(position+1 > 0) {


                        RecordsProducts records = recordsListProduct.get(position);
                        product_id = records.getId();
//                                                Toast.makeText
//                                                        (getContext(), "Selected : " + product_id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
//                                                        .show();
                        Log.e("product_id", product_id);
                        productname = records.getProductname();
                        autoproduct_name.setText(productname);
  getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);
                    }
                }
                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                }
            });
```

Comment: Let me understand you right, you are trying to create an autocomplete text that shows the autocomplete text asa table view under the text?

Comment: @PRE yes........

Answer (score 1):

I have a code that does just that, since it is a little bit long and I don't think is going to be appropriate to put it all here, I am going to share a link. Basically what I did is create a fragment where `TextView` and `TableView` lives under and that I populate interactively with the text and locations I get (Because in my case it is a location autocomplete).

https://github.com/eduasinco/MeetEat/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/comeaqui/eduardorodriguez/comeaqui/utilities/place_autocomplete